# How to register different services for different environments in ASP.NET MVC 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

What is the right way to configure services for different environments?

For example I want to add FakeService to services collection for DEV configuration and RealService for Release configuration.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    /* Need to check environment */
    services.AddSingleton<IService, FakeService>();
    ....
}
```

Comment: The `Startup` class constructor and `Configure()` methods both get passed an `IApplicationEnvironment` parameter which you can check.  Not sure how to get this datum to `ConfigureServices()` though ... and the generated method has a comment that it gets called by the runtime.  I'm guessing you already know this though :(

Comment: I can see using fake services for unit testing ... but wouldn't you want to use a "real" service -- a non-production instance, to be sure -- for development and (integration / acceptance) testing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MVC 6 has a value that defines what environment it is, this can be set by the environment variable ASPNET_ENV.  You can grab that value from IHostingEnvironment:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var env = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
        Console.WriteLine("Development");
    else if (env.IsProduction())
        Console.WriteLine("Production");
    else if (env.IsEnvironment("MyCustomEnvironment"))
        Console.WriteLine("MyCustomEnvironment");
}
```

You can set the value in VS2015 on your project by Right-click > Properties > Debug > Environment Variables:

[image: Environment variables]

Here's some more info on [configuring with environment variables](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/taking-control-of-configuration-in-mvc6/).

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of reading this from your configuration file, and making a decision in code accordingly:

```
bool isDev = Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsDev"]);

if (isDev) {
    services.AddSingleton<IService, FakeService>();
} else {
    services.AddSingleton<IService, RealService>();
}
```

Another option is to use compiler directives:

```
if #DEBUG
    services.AddSingleton<IService, FakeService>();
#else
    services.AddSingleton<IService, RealService>();
#endif
```

Comment: AppSettings is < MVC 6

Answer (score 1):

The answer currently with more upvotes proposes this:

```cs
var env = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
if (env.IsDevelopment())
...
```

However, this causes a warning:

> ASP0000   Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.

There's a better and simpler way that avoids that issue:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
...
```

Answer (score 0):

While in debug configuration there is a DEBUG defined constant (automatically defined by Visual Studio) while there is no such constant defined for release mode.

`if #DEBUG` will work only for debug.

Check out the conditional methods https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288458(v=vs.71).aspx

Use `[Conditional("DEV")]` or `[Conditional("RELEASE")]` before that method. It will execute when it matches mentioned configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a layer of indirection.  That is, use the IoC container to inject the appropriate version of the service:

```
services.AddService(container.Resolve<IMyServiceType>);
```

... of course you'll need to make sure the container returns the appropriate type for each environment.

I'm not sure you can do this with the default IoC container though; you might need to replace it with Ninject, Autofac, or whatever.

Comment: That would just create a cyclic reference and would possibly cause a stack overflow exception.

Comment: It's supposed to be possible to replace the default container with another IoC container.  (Of course there are methods that would need to be added to support ASP.NET.)  But it seems to me the two considerations are orthogonal to each other?  So I'm not sure I understand why this would created a cyclic reference.

Comment: in your answer you don't mention a second container, so I had to assume you use the built-in container for both registration and resolving and that would cause an infinite loop.